# Multiply columns of dataframe together if some data missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 columns of data in a dataframe, where most of the time all 4 columns have data.

In some cases, there are empty cells in the dataframe.

How can I multiply the first 3 occurring values together regardless of their position? I have tried things like df.loc to no avail.

Data below.

```
{Input Dataframe}
    A        B        C        D
0   (empty)  58       44       62
1   42       34       (empty)  46
2   85       (empty)  81       91
3   54       43       42       56

{Output Dataframe}
0 158224
1 65688
2 626535
3 97524
```

After multiplying them together, I would like to add a weighting to the scores as well. e.g. first value is 50% of the final score, second value is 35% of final score, third value is 15% of final score. This is would be a sum of the products multiplied by the weighting factor.

Math for row 0 would result in the following:
58x0.5 + 44x0.35 + 62x0.15 = 53.7

```
{Weighted Sum Result}
0 53.7
1 39.8
2 84.5
3 48.35
```

Comment: Row 1 should be `42 x 34 x 46 = 65688` no?

Comment: Yes, it should be. I messed up the data in the copy / paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) + [`groupby head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-head) + [`prod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.prod.html#pandas-series-prod):

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).head(3).prod(level=0)
```

Another option is [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) on axis=1 with [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html#pandas-series-dropna) + [`head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.head.html#pandas-series-head) + [`prod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.prod.html#pandas-series-prod):

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.dropna().head(3).prod(), axis=1)
```

Both produce:

```
0    158224.0
1     65688.0
2    626535.0
3     97524.0
dtype: float64
```

---

Edit to include ability to do further processing with separate values via [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot-table) + [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna):

```
values = df.stack().reset_index()
values = values.pivot_table(index='level_0',
                            columns=values.groupby('level_0').cumcount(),
                            values=0).dropna(axis=1)
```

`values`:

```
            0     1     2
level_0                  
0        58.0  44.0  62.0
1        42.0  34.0  46.0
2        85.0  81.0  91.0
3        54.0  43.0  42.0
```

Then further operations can be performed, like weighting:

```
weights = [.5, .35, .15]
weighted_sum = (values * weights).sum(axis=1)
```

`weighted_sum`:

```
level_0
0    53.70
1    39.80
2    84.50
3    48.35
dtype: float64
```

---

DataFrame Used:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [nan, 42.0, 85.0, 54.0], 'B': [58.0, 34.0, nan, 43.0],
                   'C': [44.0, nan, 81.0, 42.0], 'D': [62, 46, 91, 56]})
```

Comment: Do you know of any alternatives to head? I should have clarified in the original question that I might want to do something like a weighted average to each of the cells. e.g. first value is 50% of the final score, second value is 35% of final score, third value is 15% of final score.